# DbContext has been disposed when using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm still getting error like this:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

I'm using Ninject and when I use injected repository (`InRequestScope`) to `HomeController` everything work good, but when I use injected class `InSingletonScope`, which has another repository injected by `InRequestScope`, then I get this error.

My `InSingletonScope` class:

```
public class SettingsManager : ISettingsManager
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRepository _configurationRepository;

    private readonly Lazy<ApplicationSettings> _applicationSettings;
    public ApplicationSettings Application { get { return _applicationSettings.Value; } }

    private SettingsManager(IConfigurationRepositorycontext)
    {
         _configurationService = context;

        _applicationSettings = new Lazy<ApplicationSettings>(() => new ApplicationSettings(context));
    }
}
```

`ApplicationSettings` class:

```
 public class ApplicationSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
 {
    private readonly IConfigurationRepository _configurationRepository;

    public ApplicationSettings(IConfigurationRepository context)
    {
        _configurationRepository= context;
    }

    public string GetItem()
    {
        return _configurationService.GetApplicationConfiguration(4).First().Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

My `ConfigurationRepository`:

```
public class ConfigurationRepository : BaseRepository<Configuration>, IConfigurationRepository
{
    public ConfigurationRepository(DbContext _dbContext)
        : base(_dbContext)
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<ConfigurationDTO> GetApplicationConfiguration(int domainId)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<Configuration>()
            .Where(x => x.DomainId == 5)
            .Select(x => new ConfigurationDTO
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                Value = x.Value
            });
    }
}
```

And in this repository I get an error.

My `NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices` method:

```
        kernel.Bind<ISettingsManager>().To<SettingsManager>().InSingletonScope();

        kernel.Bind<IConfigurationRepository>().To<ConfigurationRepository>().InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<EntitiesDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

Where could be the problem?

EDIT
The problem disappears when I change DbContext to EntitiesDbContext:

```
 public class ConfigurationRepository : BaseRepository<Configuration>, IConfigurationRepository
    {
        public ConfigurationRepository(EntitiesDbContext _dbContext)
            : base(_dbContext)
        {
        }
}
```

So my binding in Ninject is wrong?

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<EntitiesDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

Why?

I have new model:

```
public partial class EntitiesDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EntitiesDbContext ()
            : base("name=EntitiesDbContext ")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Configuration> Configuration { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you implement IDisposable in BaseRepository ?

Comment: @fredho Why this is needed? In Base repository I have DBContext injected by Ninject, so the disposing is make by Ninject. Am I wrong?

Comment: what if you take the Lazy off on the ApplicationSettings in Settings Manager?  this might make it so the dbcontext is immediately used before it is disposed

Comment: (edit:  I dont believe my above comment about Lazy will work) I believe the reason that it works with EntitiesDbContext because it is not using your binding and the context is not getting disposed at the end of the request

Comment: @MarkOlsen But I see that debug hit my binding DbContext to EntitiesDbContext.How can I fix this?

Comment: I think that when EntitiesDbContext is the parameter, it doesn't use your binding because the binding is looking for DbContext to inject the EntitiesDbContext.  When it finds EntitiesDbContext, it goes back to its default behavior of just making Transient objects.  If you want to to use request scope, I think the parameter has to be DbContext (which will then exhibit your problem).  The easiest way to solve this would be to make the settings manager request scope but you will pull the settings from the database every request that needs them. Not sure if thats an option

Comment: @MarkOlsen I want to use `InSingletonScope`, because SettiingsManager must be Singleton. When I change SettingsManager binding to `InReqestScope`, everything work fine. So, `InRequestScope` can't exist in `InSingletonScope`?

Comment: Since SettingsManager is a Singleton, it lasts for the entirety of the application.  A request scoped object is disposed of at the end of the web request where it was used.  So basically once the web request is over,  the DbContext is disposed and now the Singleton is holding on to a disposed instance.  So yes,  its not a good idea to use a request scoped object in a Singleton.

Comment: @MarkOlsen So what can I do with this situation: I want to have one SettingsManager (per application, so static or singleton), which will be some kind of container for specific managers like ApplicationSettingsManager (which will be reading from DB) and GeneralSettingsManager (read from web.config). And for  ApplicationSettingsManager I want to have injected DbContext, because of operation on DB.